# Archive not found but it's there

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, wav

So I'm trying to open various wav archives and trying to use less line of code because I'm actually lazy to write the same thing 5 time if I could use one cycle for everything.

```
num_experimento = 3
vocals = ["a","e","i","o","u"]

trabajos = "{letter}-int{number}.wav"

for vocal in vocals:
    for n in range (1, num_experimento+1):
        archive = trabajos.format(letter=vocal, number=n) #http://blog.espol.edu.ec/telg1001/audio-en-formato-wav/
        sound = wavfile.read(archive)
        print(sound)
```

The thing is that it says it can't find the archive

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 7>()
      8 for n in range (1, num_experimento+1):
      9     archive = trabajos.format(letter=vocal, number=n) #http://blog.espol.edu.ec/telg1001/audio-en-formato-wav/
---> 10     sound = wavfile.read(archive)
     11     print(sound)

File c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py:647, in read(filename, mmap)
    645     mmap = False
    646 else:
--> 647     fid = open(filename, 'rb')
    649 try:
    650     file_size, is_big_endian = _read_riff_chunk(fid)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a-int1.wav'
```

I'll leave an image of the environment and the files I'm working, and maybe I'm blind but I see the same archive name in the file I'm currently working.
What am I doing wrong?
[An image of the file I'm currently working on, with the code and the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdePj.png)

I'm working in spanish, that's why of the name changes between the image and the code I posted here,but it's the same

Comment: Add `print(os.getcwd())` to your code (and an `import os` if you're not already doing so). You may discover your working directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks, just added and it showed me it was one file away of where i actually put the archives. I dont know how to explain, that's the best way i could

Comment: Isn't it good practice to write code in English, even if you are working with a spanish documented Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @LucasVazquez it's for easier comprehension for me, sometimes I got lost even with the comments

Comment: Está perfecto entonces! jaja